# LinkedIn V2 API permission for reading socialActions and Shares

Tags: linkedin-api

I get no permissions error when i make the following linkedIn V2 Api call
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{share URN}?oauth2_access_token={access token}

LinkedIn Api Response

```
{
serviceErrorCode: 100,
message: "Not enough permissions to access /socialActions/{target} GET ",
status: 403
}
```

These are the 
[Default application Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9fft.png)

can someone please help on this. (Need to make this work on V2 api)

Comment: Hey @akhileshwar did you solve this? I am also getting the same problem ...

Comment: How did you find the documentation for these endpoints? I was under the impression these endpoints were only accessible after gaining access to LinkedIn Marketing API which allows the use of r_ad_campaigns permission scope. I still am encountering the same issue and am not sure where else to look for more help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your API call will return a 403 Forbidden error if you do not have the appropriate admin permission to interact with the target company.

The following endpoints are the only ones available for public use:

Profile API — /v1/people/~
Share API — /v1/people/~/shares
Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}

If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g. Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search, etc.) you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of the endpoints that are not listed above.

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Comment: With partner program you need to get rw_organization permission for your app and while authendication also.

Answer (score -4):

On using the updated V2 access token, the endpoints were working good.