# How to make LinkedIn V2 Share (SocialActions) work correctly?

Tags: linkedin-api

We recently obtained the r_ad_campaigns permission to work with the LinkedIn V2 API:

- https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/lms/marketing-analytics/quick-start#
- https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/network-update-social-actions

To work correctly, I have obtained a new TOKEN with the new permission: r_ad_campaigns

I have made the following 3 calls with this new token:

- https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{share URN}?oauth2_access_token=TOKEN
- https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{share URN}/comments?oauth2_access_token=TOKEN
- https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{share URN}/likes?oauth2_access_token=TOKEN

And they all return the same result:
{"serviceErrorCode": 100, "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET / socialActions / {share URN}", "status": 403}

The same thing happens with these post:

- [Why does LinkedIn v2 Share API give not enough permissions error on any v2/shares endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372629/why-does-linkedin-v2-share-api-give-not-enough-permissions-error-on-any-v2-share)
- [LinkedIn V2 API permission for reading socialActions and Shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584557/linkedin-v2-api-permission-for-reading-socialactions-and-shares)

Please, does anyone know how to solve this problem and that it works correctly? Is it important.

Comment: I'm currently having the same error but no only on shares bu also on skills. And I guess it is for all linkedin v2 endpoints.

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue, I have the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's working in my case, this problem related to permission

Follow these steps,

- Open Url, https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/
- Goto products
- Select all products
- Marketing Developer Platform Product need some days to be approved
- If all products are successfully installed
- Check OAuth 2.0 scopes permissions to access data using your app